# One Textbox Value Greater then other, Avoid and Beep

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, comparison

I have two Textboxes in Visual Basic 2010
`Textbox1`
`Textbox2`
Now I want that if user enter value(integer) in Textbox2, if the value in `Textbox2` is Greater than `Textbox1`, so this will do a beep and also avoid him to do like this
`Example:` If User write `5` in Textbox1 and now he is writing `8` in `Textbox2` so as `8` is grater than `5`, so i want that `Textbox2` ignore with a beep.
I have this code but this is not working, please if some one help me:

> ```
> Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
>
>     Dim valx1 As Integer
>     Dim valx2 As Integer
>
>     valx1 = (Val(TextBox1.Text))
>     valx2 = (Val(TextBox2.Text))
>
>
>     If (valx1) > (valx2) Then
>         Beep()
>         e.Handled = True
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will suits your requirement, By the way using a beeb sound for alerting the user, will make him/her disturbed.

```
 Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

   if val(TextBox1.Text.trim) > val(TextBox2.Text.trim & e.keychar) then
          Beep()
          e.Handled = True
    end if

End Sub
```